# Why this is a covering map between compact Riemann surfaces?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, riemann-surfaces

Let $F:X\rightarrow Y$ be a non constant holomorphic map between compact Riemann surfaces
, If we delet the branch points (in $Y$) of $F$ and all their pre-images(in $X$), we obtain a map $F:U\rightarrow V$ between 2- manifolds which is a *covering map* in the sense of *topology*: every point of the target $V$ has an open neighborhood $N\subseteq V$ such that the inverse image of $N$ under $F$ breaks into a disjoint open sets $M_i\subseteq U$ with the map $F$ sending each $M_i$ homeomorphically onto $N$, 
I do not understand why this is a covering map and I can not visualize why inverse image of $N$ is like that, please could any one make me understand with an example of map between known compact riemann surfaces?

Comment: Do you understand why $F : U \to V$ is a local homeomorphism? Do you know that a proper local homeomorphism is a covering map?

Comment: NO I do not understand and know

Answer (score 7):

The important point is that, once you have deleted all the branch points and their preimages, the function $F : U \to V$ is a differentiable function whose derivative is everywhere invertible. So, by the implicit function theorem, $F$ is a local homeomorphism.

Now, local homeomorphism is a notion quite close to “covering map”: a map is a local homeomorphism if for every $x \in U$ you have neighbourhoods $\mathscr V_x$ and $\mathscr V_{y}$ such that $f$ is an homeomorphism $\mathscr V_x \to \mathscr V_y$ ($y$ being $f(x)$). Roughly, it being a covering map means that for every $y \in V$ you can find a neighbourhood $\mathscr V_y$ such that *for every* preimage $x$ there is a neighbourhood $\mathscr V_x$ such that $f$ induces an homeomorphism $f : \mathscr V_x \to \mathscr V_y$. (I'm conscious that this “definition” isn't equivalent to the correct one. But that's what is important: in a covering map, you have *one* neighbourhood in the target which works uniformly for *every* preimage). With this slogan in mind, it is quite easy to cook up examples of local homeomorphism which aren't covering maps when a point has infinitely many preimages. But it's basically the only problem, as shows the classical proposition : *a proper map $f$ between locally compact spaces is a covering map if and only if it is a local homeomorphism*. I'm sure you can find a proof in any textbook about covering maps, but the key is that properness allows you to have a uniform control on all the preimages of your $\mathscr V_y$.

So, your map $F : U \to V$ is a local homeomorphism, $F : X \to Y$ was clearly proper because $X$ is compact, so now you only have to check that deleting the branch points and *all* their preimages hasn't destructed properness. (If you think of a proper map as a map such that $f(x)$ goes to infinity as soon as $x$ does, it should be quite clear because of the continuity of $F : X \to Y$. And you have your proof!

(I reckon that what I have said is nothing like a rigourous proof. But you can find such a proof with all the necessary details in any textbook about compact Riemann surfaces, so I thought explaining to you why this result is reasonable was the best thing to do.)